# warning: /service/railo-jetty: unable to open supervice/ok: file does not exist

Tags: railo, runit

I'm trying to start railo-jetty using supervisor and I'm getting an error:

**warning: /service/railo-jetty: unable to open supervice/ok: file does not exist**

What could be the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by creating a symlink of the railo-jetty folder in /etc/services